# ORMExecuteQuery returns query instead of entities

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Is it possible to have ORMExecuteQuery returns a query result instead of entities?

Comment: I think your best bet is to pass the result of that function call to entityToQuery(). I don't know of any other config or underlying Java method tied to the function's class.

Comment: What do you mean by "returns a query result"?

Comment: Yeah I know you can use entityToQuery(), but what I'm after is a way to reduce server load (by telling it to just return the query result in some cases instead of wasting time creating entities from the query), so entityToQuery wouldn't help. It's okay, I'll figure out other ways to reduce load.